# Retrieving Image using url stored in database

Tags: c#

I am storing the user photos in a folder and their URLs in my SQL database. The URLs are getting stored and I am also able to retrieve them but when I link this URL to the ImageURL property of asp:Image control, the Image is not getting retrieved. Rather, I see just an empty box in my website. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried pasting the URLs into your browser?

Answer (score 1):

The URL you store in the database is a local filesystem URL, it is something like `d:\picture_files\first_picture.jpg`. When you send it to the browser, the browser tries to look at it *on the user's machine*, not your server - because it arrives as a local URL.

What you need to do is create a webpage that returns an image, such as '/show_image?imageid=123`. The server will see the request, look image ID 123 in the database up, and send the image to the browser. That way your users will be able to see the images.

Comment: With agreeing on your answer, I was going to answer a similar one :)

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the image to array of bytes ' byte[]  '
by using streem
and change datatype of field in sql database to image
and store the array on database
and when you need pic,get the array of bytes from database and convert to image again

///code to convert image to bytes 'using system.IO'

```
    byte[] myFile;
    using (Stream inStream = File.Open("path of image", FileMode.Open))
    {
            myFile = new byte[inStream.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < inStream.Length; i++)
            {
                myFile[i]=((byte)inStream.ReadByte());
            }        
    }
```

///code to convert bytes to image

```
     Stream stream = new MemoryStream(myFile);
    Image myImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
```